# Xamarin Forms System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion, sfschedule

I have a page that contains a Syncfusion weekly `SfSchedule` when I try to open the page it gives me this error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation and the InnerException is:
>   {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}. The App crashes on
>   InitializeComponent(); line.

The I'm filling the data source of the schedule from my realm database.

This is the XAML code:

```
<ContentPage.Padding>
   <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
             iOS="0, 20, 0, 0"
             Android="0"
             WinPhone="0" />
 </ContentPage.Padding>

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
  <ViewModels:ActivitiesViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<WeeklySchedule:SfSchedule x:Name="activitiesWeeklySchedule"
                      BackgroundColor="White"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      ScheduleView="WeekView"
                      ShowAppointmentsInline="True">
</WeeklySchedule:SfSchedule>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
    Realm realm;
    ScheduleAppointmentCollection collection;
    public TeacherWeeklyView() {
        InitializeComponent();
        collection = new ScheduleAppointmentCollection() { };
        var config = new RealmConfiguration() { SchemaVersion = 3 };
        realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
        var activities = realm.All<ActivitiesItems>();
        foreach (var item in activities) {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.ActivitySubject);
           collection.Add(activity);
        }
        activitiesWeeklySchedule.DataSource = collection;
     }
```

This problem started when the Syncfusion packages needed to be updated so I updated it but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it I deleted this part of code:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
   <ViewModels:ActivitiesViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```